# Why is this program not running (Python)

Tags: python, random, import

I'm trying to write a program in Python that flips a coin and returns the longest series of heads and tails. It asks the user how many times to flip the coin. For some reason my program isn't running and I cant figure out why. I don't know why it isn't asking the user for the "number of flips" and "as a character string" for example.

```
import random

def flip():
    flipValue = random.randint(1,2)
    if flipValue == 1:
        side = "Heads"
    else:
        side = "Tails"
    return side

def nStreak():
    number = int(input("Number of flips: "))
    chars = int(input("As a character string: "))
    series = 0
    heads = 0
    tails = 0
    longest_h = 0
    longest_t = 0
    while series != number:
        side = flip()
        series += 1
        if side == "Heads":
            heads += 1
            tails = 0
            if heads == chars:
                longest_h += 1
                heads = 0
        if side == "Tails":
            tails += 1
            heads = 0
            if tails == chars:
                longest_t += 1
                tails = 0
    print("Number of heads streaks: ", longest_h)
    print("Number of tails streaks: ", longest_t)
```

When I run it I get nothing.

Comment: you didn't call the functions

Comment: You have two methods defined, but none are called. Your script just does the method definitions, and then exits.

Comment: How would I write this program without the def's? Like if I wanted to get rid of def flip() and def nStreak()? This is for an assignment and my teacher hasn't taught us how to use def yet so I added it anyways but now regret it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function at the last line.

`nStreak()`

Or else it won't execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your script add `nStreak()` with no identation.